# How to pass int variable from numberpicker in one activity to another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am using a numberpicker in activity 1 for the user to select how many times they will tap a button moving randomly around the screen in activity 2 and once they reach that number it should direct them to activity 3. I am having problems with the last part, in that it does not send the user to activity 3 when they reach the number they selected. I think it has to do with my code of passing the number from the number selector in activity 1 to activity 3.

```
public class DexterityTrainer extends AppCompatActivity {

int mreps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dexterity_trainer);


    NumberPicker np = findViewById(R.id.repnum);
    np.setMinValue(5);
    np.setMaxValue(100);
    np.setOnValueChangedListener(onValueChangeListener);
}


    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener onValueChangeListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        mreps = picker.getValue();

    }
};


// takes you back to first screen
public void goHome(View view){
    Intent startHome = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(startHome);
}
// Should start 2nd Activity and pass variable
public void startdex(View view){
    Intent dexAct = new Intent(this, DexterityActivity.class);
    getIntent().putExtra("reps", mreps);
    startActivity(dexAct);
}
```

Activity 2 then starts,

```
public class DexterityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int mcount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dexterity);

    final TextView displaycount = findViewById(R.id.displaycount);
    final Button btn = findViewById(R.id.tap_button);
    int reps = getIntent().getIntExtra("reps", -1);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mcount++;
            displaycount.setText(Integer.toString(mcount));
        }
    });


    final DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Random R = new Random();
                    final float dx = R.nextFloat() * displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                    final float dy = R.nextFloat() * displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                    final Timer timer = new Timer();
                    btn.animate()
                            .x(dx)
                            .y(dy)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1500);


    Intent startlog = new Intent(DexterityActivity.this, TherapyLog.class);


    if (reps == mcount){
        startActivity(startlog);
    }



}
```

At first I thought there may have been something wrong with the if statement, but if I set the default value to 0 it will launch activity 3 right after activity 1

Comment: solved it myself

Comment: In that case you should probably either withdraw the question or add the solution as an answer. SO exists to provide a searchable repository of problems *with solutions*, not just to help you personally.

Comment: I'll vote to close, though. You'll have three days to add an answer once it's closed.